# Linux Mint 17 Cinnamin + MySQL + turn OFF autostart

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mysql, startup

I have tried all the suggestions in hours of googling and still when I reboot and run service mysql status my server is running.  since i only use mysql for database testing with my java apps i don't need it running all the time.

i tried renaming mysql.conf to mysql.conf.old and that just diabled mysql from even manually starting.

i've also tried update-rc.d   disable to no effect.

i also tried using bum and looking for mysql but it does not have a checkmark even tho it obviously is starting up on reboot.

thanks for your help!

updated with requested output:
 $ ls /etc/rc2.d/*myslq*
ls: cannot access /etc/rc2.d/*myslq*: No such file or directory

$ dpkg -l | grep mysql

ii  libdbd-mysql-perl 4.025-1 amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient18:amd64    5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2     amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  libmysqlcppconn7  1.1.3-5 amd64        MySQL Connector for C++ (library)
ii  mysql-apt-config  0.5.3-1 all          Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
ii  mysql-client-5.5  5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2     amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.5     5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2     amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common      5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2     all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
rc  mysql-common-5.6  5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     all          MySQL 5.6 specific common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/my-5.6.cnf
ic  mysql-server-5.5  5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2     amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
rc  mysql-server-5.6  5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.5     5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2     amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  mysql-workbench   6.0.8+dfsg-2        amd64        MySQL Workbench - a visual database modeling, administration and queuing tool
ii  mysql-workbench-data      6.0.8+dfsg-2        all          MySQL Workbench -- architecture independent data
ii  python-mysql.connector    1.1.6-1 all          pure Python implementation of MySQL Client/Server protocol

Comment: what is the ouput of sudo runlevel?

Comment: the output of sudo runlevel = N 2

Comment: could you please show us the output of the command "ls /etc/rc2.d/*myslq* "  and "dpkg -l | grep mysql"

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to install a ncurses-based command line tool called sysv-rc-conf:

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

then run it as superuser:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

And uncheck all the boxes on every runlevel in mysql row. Example screen of the program pasted below:

[image: sysv-rc-conf]

Comment: I actually prefer installing chkconfig

Comment: this looks like an interesting application, can i still turn on mysql manually from the terminal?  i'm worried i will be tempted to turn off things "i don't need" and my system won't start up (done that with windows ha!)